# NodeJS Express 4.0 routing regex error

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

After updating the express module to the 4.0 version the following url regexp stop working:

```
app.get("/admin/list001/(userid/:userid)?/(name/:name)?/(email/:email)?/order/:order/field/:field/first/:first/rows/:rows/curriculums.:format(json)", function(request, response){
```

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:
/^\/admin\/list001\/(?(?:([^\/]+?))\/(?:([^\/]+?)))?\/name(?:\/([^\/]+?))?\/email(?:\/([^\/]+?))?\/order\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/field\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/first\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/rows\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/curriculums(?:\.(json))\/?$/:
Invalid group
```

There are any other way of achieving the same result?

Edit: (progress)

```
/admin/list001(/userid/:userid)?(/name/:name)?(/email/:email)?(/order/:order)?(/field/:field)?(/first/:first)?(/rows/:rows)?/curriculums.:format(json)
```

This works. But the request.params vars don't catch the right values:

```
{ '0': '/field/userid',
  '1': 'userid',
  '2': '/first/0',
  '3': '0',
  '4': '/rows/20',
  '5': '20',
  '6': 'json',
  userid: '/userid/true',
  name: 'true',
  email: '/name/true',
  order: 'true',
  field: '/email/true',
  first: 'true',
  rows: '/order/DESC',
  format: 'DESC' }
```

Comment: escape all the forward slashes.

Comment: Tried that and didn't work... same error.

Comment: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\/admin\/list001\/(?(?:([^\/]+?))\/(?:([^\/]+?)))?\/curriculums(?:\.(json))\/?$/: Invalid group

Comment: I made progress, I think: /admin/list001(/userid/:userid)?(/name/:name)?(/email/:email)?(/order/:order)?(/field/:field)?(/first/:first)?(/rows/:rows)?/curriculums.:format(json), this works but know the request.params vars don't catch the right values...